# Printing dictionary key as many times as its value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with the below key value pairing:

```
mango 2
orange 3
banana 4
```

Based on the value, I want the key be printed as many times.
Expected output in the xlsx file: (first column only)

```
mango
mango
orange
orange
orange
banana
banana
banana
banana
```

I tried the below:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('TEST.xlsx')
sheet=workbook.add_worksheet() 
row=0
for key in list(values.keys()):
    for i in range(int(values[key])):
        sheet.write_column(row,0,key)
        row=row+1   
workbook.close()
```

I am getting the below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help.

Comment: What is `values`? Is it really a dictionary?

Comment: That code looks quite complex for such a simple operation. Why not use `dict.items()`? One of the answers seems to indicate that you're simply misusing `write_column()`, can you clarify things?

Comment: Please do not share code/data as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `xlsxwriter`'s [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html).

> The write_column() method can be used to write a list of data in one go. This is useful for converting the results of a database query into an Excel worksheet. **The write() method is called for each element of the data.**

If you pass your data as a list, after your loop it will write your data correctly.

```
column = []
for key, value in d.items():
    for i in range(value):
        column.append(key)

sheet.write_column(row = 0, col = 0, data = column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code without including output to notebook, that should be something like what you have down already:

```
  def get_column_keys(storeFruits, val):
    reps = []
    for key in storeFruits.keys():
        if storeFruits[key] == val:
            reps.append(key)
    return reps
```

Comment: Why not use `dict.items()`, and why the `camelCase` variable name?